# Icon not showing up with ionic framework on phonegap build

Tags: icons, config, phonegap-build

I'm using phonegap build to wrap a project I made with ionic. I cannot get phonegap build to recognize my icon.png in the root directory. I could only get phonegap build to recognize my config.xml file in the www directory (rather than the root directory) and I tried my icon.png and splash.png files in that directory with no luck. Where do I put these files so that phonegap build will recognize them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They go in the root directory.

You must refer to them using the proper path with config.xml.

I'd be more concerned that config.xml in the root directory is not being recognised. You don't need a www directory at all. Why have it?

I use this structure with no problems.

```
- Root
--images
--scripts
--css
--splash
--icons
```

You can put your iOS icons in icons/ios or you could have a different structure and use images/ios/splash for example.

The three important things are:

a. Correct path.
b. You MUST have default icons and splash screens.
c. You should specify platform for your images.